# Need help with setting up comet code

Tags: jquery, nginx, comet, node.js, persistent-connection

Does anyone know off a way or maybe think its possible to connect Node.js with Nginx http push module to maintain a persistent connection between client and browser.

I am new to comet so just don't understand the publishing etc maybe someone can help me with this.

What i have set up so far is the following. I downloaded the jQuery.comet plugin and set up the following basic code:

> ### Client JavaScript

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    function updateFeed(data) {
        $('#time').text(data);
    }

    function catchAll(data, type) {
        console.log(data);
        console.log(type);
    }

    $.comet.connect('/broadcast/sub?channel=getIt');
    $.comet.bind(updateFeed, 'feed');
    $.comet.bind(catchAll);

    $('#kill-button').click(function() {
        $.comet.unbind(updateFeed, 'feed');
    });
</script>
```

What I can understand from this is that the client will keep on listening to the url followed by /broadcast/sub=getIt. When there is a message it will fire updateFeed.

Pretty basic and understandable IMO.

> ### Nginx http push module config

default_type  application/octet-stream;
sendfile        on;
keepalive_timeout  65;
push_authorized_channels_only off;

```
server {
  listen       80;
  location /broadcast {
    location = /broadcast/sub {
      set $push_channel_id $arg_channel;
      push_subscriber;
      push_subscriber_concurrency broadcast;
      push_channel_group broadcast;
    }

    location = /broadcast/pub {
      set $push_channel_id $arg_channel;
      push_publisher;
      push_min_message_buffer_length 5;
      push_max_message_buffer_length 20;
      push_message_timeout 5s;
      push_channel_group broadcast;
    }
  }
}
```

Ok now this tells nginx to listen at port 80 for any calls to /broadcast/sub and it will give back any responses sent to /broadcast/pub.

Pretty basic also. This part is not so hard to understand, and is well documented over the internet. Most of the time there is a ruby or a php file behind this that does the broadcasting.

> ***My idea is to have node.js broadcasting `/broadcast/pub`. I think this will let me have `persistent streaming data` from the server to the client without breaking the connection. I tried the long-polling approach with looping the request but I think this will be more efficient.***

Or is this not going to work.

> ### Node.js file

Now to create the Node.js i'm lost. First off all I don't know how to have node.js to work in this way.

The setup I used for long polling is as follows:

```
var sys = require('sys'), 
http = require('http');
http.createServer(function (req, res) {
    res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
    res.write(new Date());
    res.close();
    seTimeout('',1000);
}).listen(8000);
```

This listens to port 8000 and just writes on the response variable.

For long polling my `nginx.config` looked something like this:

```
server {
  listen      80;
  server_name _;

  location / {
    proxy_pass   http://mydomain.com:8080$request_uri;
    include      /etc/nginx/proxy.conf;
  }
 }
```

This just redirected the port 80 to 8000 and this worked fine.

> ***Does anyone have an idea on how to have Node.js act in a way Comet understands it. Would be really nice and you will help me out a lot.***

### Recources

***used***

- [An example where this is done with ruby instead of Node.js](http://www.igvita.com/2009/10/21/nginx-comet-low-latency-server-push/)
- [jQuery.comet](http://github.com/SeanOC/jquery.comet)
- [Nginx HTTP push module homepage](http://pushmodule.slact.net/)
- [Faye: a Comet client and server for Node.js and Rack](http://blog.jcoglan.com/2010/02/02/faye-a-comet-client-and-server-for-node-js-and-rack/)

To use faye I have to install the comet client, but I want to use the one supplied with Nginx. Thats why I don't just use faye. The one nginx uses is much more optimzed.

***extra***

- [Persistant connections](http://gist.github.com/258696)
- [Going evented with Node.js](http://www.nakedjavascript.com/going-evented-with-nodejs)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at [your link](http://www.igvita.com/2009/10/21/nginx-comet-low-latency-server-push/) it seems to me that all pub/sub work is done by Nginx, Ruby code is used only to test it and send messages. Clients are still using long polling:

> In the script above, every five seconds a publisher emits a new event to our Nginx server, which in turn, pushes the data to two subscribers **which have long-polling connections open** and are waiting for data. Once the message is sent to each subscriber, Nginx closes their connections and the clients then immediately **re-establish them** to wait for the next available message.

Nginx serves as simple retranslator for messages (very clever setup BTW, thanks for the link).

To put it short: browsers aren't capable for this sort of connection you trying to do. This is what [WebSockets](http://dev.w3.org/html5/websockets/) were invented for.

Later i'll make some code in Node.js to use this setup with Nginx (I'm interested in it too).

Comment: Hello thank you for commenting again. I think we both like this technology. I already found out that it still is long polling, but I think this is a little more elegant than traditional long-polling. I have managed to set up a small example using this. I am still busy building on top of it. I will post it when I am done with it, and I am interested in seeing your implementation also.

Comment: By the way Nginx has also got a module to extract the data from the PHP session. This will completely solve the 'problem' I had with Node.js and the sessions. You solved it a little for me but I think doing it in Nginx is even better, I can just pass it to Node. I am looking forward to your solution regarding nginx's http push. I am stuck on publishing the right way.